# Can I read a jmap dump with jprofiler?

Tags: jprofiler, jmap

When I create a dump using jmap

```
jmap -J-d64 -heap:format=b ${pid}
```

Can I open the resulting `heap.bin` somehow in JProfiler?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently it's a simple as renaming the file to have a `.hprof` extension